# Why does this pattern work: $1 \cdot{1} = 1, 11 \cdot{11} = 121, 111 \cdot{111} = 12321\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, arithmetic

I have recently learned about pattern that goes like this:

$$\begin{align}
1^2 &= 1\\
11^2 &= 121\\
111^2 &= 12,321\\
1,111^2 &= 1,234,321\\
11,111^2 &= 123,454,321.
\end{align}$$

It is a very cool pattern, but after a bit it stops:

$$1,111,111,111^2 = 1,234,567,900,987,654,321$$

My main question:

> Why does this pattern work?

A side question that's less important:

> Is there an algebraic equation to describe this pattern?

Comment: Have you tried doing those multiplications by hand, the way you learn in school? I think that's actually the best way to see how this pattern appears and breaks.

Comment: @Arthur: No, I read about it in a book. I tried that, and it helped with the second question. Thank you!

Comment: This reminds me of *der Zahlenteufel*, a book I read some time ago :)

Comment: @MaximiliqnJanisch This pattern is indeed featured in that book. I loved it when I was small, and I will read it for my daughter when she gets older.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: In fact, that is the book I read about it in!

Comment: The pattern doesn't really stop, it just overlaps itself. It'd go longer if you used base 100 instead of base 10. Or just give the digits some extra space to expand into. Here's a live [Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjDsKgDAQRHtPMaQyMYVaBgJeRTSRFFllFby--YhOtfOWeVOgy_G8XM3qPHybSjzt2Gsc--3YjtI0SImwGHooVXlhlFm5Dk6aVhBMggokZMF-ZwQEAs-0uep-ff-KNIQRug7l98zymBE6DA-c0Smp&lang=sage) that does that.

Comment: On a related note, check out $(1/9)^2, (1/99)^2, (1/999)^2$, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do the maths:

```
        1 1 1 1 1
      x 1 1 1 1 1
        ---------
        1 1 1 1 1
      1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
-----------------
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

Of course the pattern only goes up to nine $1$'s, because after that you get eight hundred and ninety-ten in the billions column...

Answer (score 6):

Since OP is asking for an algebraic explanation, I will try a different approach, possibly trickier than the other answer which is elegant but not formal.

We consider the polynomial $(1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n)^2$: by expanding the square we get

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1 & x & x^2 &\cdots& x^{n-1}& x^n\\ 
\hline
x & x^2 & x^3 &\cdots& x^{n}& x^{n+1}\\ 
\hline
x^2 & x^3 & x^4 &\cdots& x^{n+1}& x^{n+2}\\ 
\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots& \vdots& \vdots\\ 
\hline
x^{n-1} & x^{n} & x^{n+1} &\cdots& x^{2n-2}& x^{2n-1}\\ 
\hline
x^n & x^{n+1} & x^{n+2} &\cdots& x^{2n-1}& x^{2n}\\ 
\hline
\end{array}$$
that is, for $n\geq 0$, and for $0\leq j\leq 2n$,
$$\begin{align}
(1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n)^2&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j} x^k\cdot x^{j-k}
+\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}\sum_{k=j-n}^{n} x^k\cdot x^{j-k}\\
&=
\sum_{j=0}^{n}x^j\sum_{k=0}^{j} 1
+\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}x^j\sum_{k=j-n}^{n} 1\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(j+1)x^j
+\sum_{j=n+1}^{2n}(2n-j+1)x^j.
\end{align}$$
In our case, we take $x=10$. The pattern works as soon as
$j+1\leq 9$ for $j=0,\dots,n$ AND $2n-j+1\leq 9$ for $j=n+1,\dots,2n$ where $9$ is the largest decimal digit, that is for $n\leq 8$.

For $n=8$ and $x=10$ we have that
$$(1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n)^2=111111111^2=12345678987654321$$
whereas for $n=9$ we get
$$(1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n)^2=1111111111^2=1234567900987654321.$$

Comment: There is no way someone asking this question could possibly trawl through the wall of notation in your answer. It's also completely unnecessary notation, to answer the question

Comment: @terrace OP is asking for an algebraic explanation, a different approach from the other answer which is more intuitive than formal.

Comment: OK, but I still think the notation is way more messy than it needs to be. I think it makes it difficult to read

Comment: @terrace Would you like to help me to improve it?

Comment: @terrace Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, +1. Sorry, I should have offered more help and constructive criticism, instead of what I wrote earlier

Comment: @terrace Never mind. Your first comment was a bit crude, but entirely acceptable.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this, but I'm afraid I am not a master of notation reading. Is there a way you can simplify this? I'm not asking for a large mathematical answer, just a simple answer.

Comment: @Mathemagician314 This is the best I can offer. I am sorry that my answer is not helpful. Anyway you have two cool answers to read ;-)

Comment: Robert, I am beginning to suspect that @Mathemagician314 is trolling us. Your answer is too complicated, mine is too simple... In any case, we have done all that could reasonably be expected of us. +1 for your unappreciated efforts!

Comment: @TonyK, I am sorry if I made you think that! Your answers definitely helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already provided some intuition behind the pattern. Here is some terminology:

- The numbers being squared, e.g. $111111$, are called [repunits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit).
- The resulting products are called [Demlo numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DemloNumber.html): $\,1, 121, 12321, 1234321,\, \dots$

---

Repunits can be written as sums of powers of $10$, and from that perspective, base-$10$ repunits are finite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). For example:
\begin{align}
111111 &= 1 + 10 + 100 + 1000 + 10000 + 100000\\
111111&=1 + 10 + 10^2 + 10^3 + 10^4 + 10^5\\\\
111111&=\displaystyle\frac{10^6-1}{10-1}\\\\
111111&=\displaystyle\frac{10^6-1}{9}
\end{align}

The last two lines above use the [formula for the sum of a finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula).

Squaring gives:

\begin{align}
111111^2 &= \left(\displaystyle\frac{10^6-1}{9}\right)^2\\
111111^2 &= \displaystyle\frac{10^{12} - 2\cdot 10^6 +1}{81}
\end{align}

In general:

$$\left(\,\underbrace{\,1111\,\dots\,1111\,}_{ n \text{ ones} } \,\right)^2 \, = \,\, \boxed{\displaystyle\frac{10^{2n} - 2\cdot 10^n +1}{81}\,}$$

---

Demlo numbers are [sequence A002477 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002477).

Answer (score 0):

well, for 1^2 it isn't very hard to figure out, but here is the basic explanation. there is one of 11, 111, 1111, etc. in each place value until there have been as many place values as there are digits of the original number (1,111; 11,110; 111,100; and 1,111,000 for example). the amount of digits in the product is equal to (*n*x2)-1, where n is the original number. then, it is like a bell curve, with the numbers determined by how many ones were in that place value. it then breaks because there is no single digit bigger than 9, and thus it moves to the next place, and ruins the symmetry.